# Why is floating point preferred over long for precise tasks?

Tags: floating-point, int, long-integer, precision, floating-accuracy

Why is float preferred for precision? Couldn't very large integers to represent the precision that float give and be deterministic across all machines? For example, an object moving 0.48124 meters in floating point could instead be represented by an object moving 48124 micrometers in int or long.

Comment: (1) You'll never have exactly 0.48124000000000000... meters.  Measurements are inherently imprecise to some degree, and that degree will always be far smaller than a double-precision float could represent.

Comment: (2) 0.48124 meters == 481.24 millimeters == 481240 micrometers.  The fact that you messed up the conversion *while talking about how good an idea it is* is a point against the practice.

Answer (score 6):

Floating-point is preferred over integers for some calculations because:

- When you multiply in a fixed-point format, the product has a new scale, so it must be adjusted or the code must be written to account for the changed scale. For example, if you adopt a format scaled by 100, so that .3 is represented with 30 and .4 is represented with 40, then multiplying 30 by 40 produces 1200, but correct answer at the same scale should be 12 (representing .12). Division needs similar adjustment.
- When the integer format overflows, many machines and programming languages do not have good support for getting the most significant portion of the result. Floating-point automatically produces the most significant portion of the result and rounds the discarded bits.
- Integer arithmetic usually truncates fractions, but floating-point rounds them (unless requested otherwise).
- Some calculations involve a large range of numbers, including both numbers that are very large and very small. A fixed-point format has a small range, but a floating-point format has a large range. You could manually track the scale with a fixed-point format, but then you are merely implementing your own floating-point using integers.
- Many machines and/or programming languages ignore integer overflow, but floating-point can handle these gracefully and/or provide notifications when they occur.
- Floating-point arithmetic is well defined and generally well implemented; bugs in it have been reduced (sometimes by painful experience). Building new do-it-yourself arithmetic is prone to bugs.
- For some functions, it is difficult to predict the scale of the result in advance, so it is awkward to use a fixed-point format. For example, consider sine. Whenever the input is near a multiple of π, sine is near zero. Because π is irrational (and transcendental), the pattern of which integers or fixed-point numbers are near multiples of π is very irregular. Some fixed-point numbers are not near multiples of π, and their sines are around .1, .5, .9, et cetera. Some fixed-point numbers are very near multiples of π, and their sines are close to zero. A few are **very** close to multiples of π, and their sines are tiny. Because of this, there is no fixed-point format of reasonable precision that can always return the result of sine without either underflowing or overflowing.

You asking about floating-point versus `long`. A 64-bit integer might have advantages over a 32-bit floating-point format in some situations, but often the proper comparison is for comparable sizes, such as 32-bit integer to 32-bit floating-point and 64-bit integer to 64-bit floating-point. In these cases, the question is whether the benefits of a dynamic scale outweigh the loss of a few bits of precision.

Comment: +1 The only point I would add to this analysis is the point made in a comment on the question by @cHao. Manual scale management introduces a source of errors that is not present in floating point arithmetic.

Comment: I concur overall but would like to add that the `sin()` discussion is true, but not so strong.  If one is going to use fix point math for angles, one usual jumps to degrees, grads, BAMs, etc. instead of radians.  The precision issue is then well controlled for that.

Comment: Except for values of `x` very near zero, a fixed point value in the range `-2 <= x < 2` will likely be more accurate for a `sin` result than would any floating-point format with the same total number of bits.  Even if there were some possible `double` value which happened to be within a part per decillion of being a multiple of pi (far beyond typical `double` precision), the number of meaningful bits in the `sin` result couldn't exceed the number of meaningful bits in the *difference* between that value and pi.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be 481.24 millimeters, which is part of where the problem shows up. Using integers (or long ints), you're very likely to run into a situation where you'll encounter some sort of rounding off. Maybe your program would *guarantee* that the smallest units you care about are millimeters, but it still leads to a somewhat ugly standard of writing units. It's not hard to figure out that 100000 millimeters == 100 meters, but it's not instantly obvious in the way that 100.000 is, and in an application where you might deal with mostly meters or kilometers, but you still want precision, is a lot more annoying to read than 3463.823.

In addition, there are plenty of situations where you *do* care about sizes beyond the inconveniently small, and while with floats you can trim the number of digits you display, the data is still there, so 3.141592653 (and so on up to whatever the floating point precision is) trimmed to 3.14 meters is a lot easier to deal with than 3141592653 nanometers

Answer (score 0):

The degree of **deterministic** behavior is *independent* of the data representation.  It just takes a longer specification to precisely define floating point math than integer math and is more confounding to implement.

IEEE floating point strives to make *floating point* deterministic across all machines.

Integers could be 1's or 2's compliment and various widths and thus not deterministic for certain calculations.  So integer math, unto itself, can troubles.

Yes, big integers could, and have been used as OP suggests.  But the F-P benefits, as @Eric Postpischil points out, are numerous.  Big ints are used in select situations including cryptography.

Watch for upcoming **decimal** floating point standards to deal with issues like banking.

Comment: Floating point in practice is NOT deterministic on the same machine, let alone different machines. Two identical programs, one compiled with -fast_math optimization and another w/out would produce different results. The reason: IEEE standard is very aggressive, and following it faithfully slows down floating point computations up to 10x. This is why many applications prefer "good enough and fast" to "IEEE-compliant and excruciatingly slow", they just don't advertise that to users. In particular, many GPUs don't even offer IEEE-compliant option, they always compile equivalently to -fast_math.

Comment: @Michael FP, may not be compliant on many, even most, CPUs, but that is not because FP itself can't be compliant but is is challenging.  Usually, as you say, the goal is speed over deterministic behavior - I concur.  A compiler that does not offer IEEE compliant FP is a business decision, not that it can't be done.  The speed issue is not driven by software, but by FP hardware.  The complexities of IEEE, as mentioned, are confounding and once hardware is fabricated, any non-compliance does indeed driven worst case performance on the order of 10x, but that is certainly not the average increase.

Comment: You wish. Take a look at "performance issues" or IEEE denorm section at the link below: on most modern CPUs worst case penalty is over 100x. In fact, on earlier Pentiums the worst case performance penalty was around 250x. And for what? For a tiny itsy-bitsy (pun intended) precision gain applicable only to numbers very close to zero? Of corse all compilers I know offer an option to disable this lunacy, and most applications happily use that option. This makes many computations much much much faster, at the cost of minimal "non-compliance" with IEEE standard.

Comment: @Michael I do not know of any desktop platform that flushes denormals to zero by default. And option -fast-math is explicitly about breaking standards-compliance, so that it's not surprising that it breaks standards-compliance. Floating-point in practice is deterministic unless you opt-in to make it unreliable, which may very well be the best choice for some, but does not contradict this answer.

Comment: Pascal, Nvidia GPUs do many non IEEE things by default, including dropping 1 bit of precision for divide and sqrt, demorm flushing, etc. And arrays of GPUs are the primary computational hardware for scientific computing because they are so fast.

Comment: Actually, my biggest objection to this answer was the assumption that there's no uniformity among integers. Unlike floats, identically defined integers (same size, same signed/unsigned kind) behave identically on all platforms, except for one small thing that was recently closed (modular arithmetic over negative divisors). Name a single modern platform that would use anything other than 2-complement integers in one of the few well-known 2^k bases for signed integer arithmetic, please.

Comment: The largest non-uniformity among integers I've found is amongst the various sizes used to represent the C `int`.  C expanded to include fixed width integers types like uint32_t, thus allowing greater determinism.  Good to know the modular math with negative divisors is addressed, much like a preceding issue with divide.  Still lurking are definitions of how to handle right-shits of negative integers where the shift >= the bit width.  A >> B, (A=100, B= 32) will result in 100 on a number of 32-bit machines, but 0 on 64-bit machines.

Comment: @Michael Came across a 2012 patent app concerning [1’s and 2’s compliment](https://www.google.com/patents/US8307253) math.  Should you wish a good answer to the “Name a single modern platform ..”, suggest you post a question on the OP or EE site.

Comment: Chux, patent is not a platform. Size of an int is a part of its definition. Anyway, this discussion I'm the comments went far enough. I'm moving it into a separate questions.

Comment: @Michael The blessing _and_ curse of the C language is that the Size of an `int` is _not_ part of its definition other than a minimum.  In that language, the `int` range must be at least -32767 to 32767.  Typically it is 2's compliment (by far the most common - something we agree on).  Today, sizes of 2, 4 & 8 bytes are found.  Non-conforming size of 1 byte occurs too.  The native size & format of an integer on a processor strongly influences but does not dictate the languages integer type definitions.  The language Java has fixed size & formats for its type, but it does not preclude any CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Although many kinds of code could use some kind of fixed values more efficiently than floating-point, different kinds of code and different situations have different requirements.  Some situations require storing numbers from zero to a million accurate to one part per thousand; others require storing numbers from zero to a one accurate to one part per billion.  A fixed-point format which is barely adequate for some purposes will be vastly overkill for others.  If a language can efficiently support working with a numbers stored in a wide variety of different formats, fixed-point math can have some pretty huge advantages.  On the other hand, it's generally easier for a language to support one to three floating-point formats than to support the many fixed-point formats that would otherwise be necessary.  Further, unless a language makes it possible for a single routine to work with a variety of fixed-point formats, use of general-purpose math routines is apt to be difficult.  Perhaps compiler technology has advanced to enough that using a wide variety of fixed-point types might be practical, but hardware floating-point technology has advanced enough to largely obviate the need for such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in some applications integers are preferred for a number of reasons. In particular, integers, unlike floating point, are translation-invariant:

```
x1 - x2 == (x1 - displacement) - (x2 - displacement)
```

This is very important in some geometric engines. For example, if you are computing a large grid of identical shapes determined by some parameter then you compute sets of identical parameters and for each set compute what happens in one of its representative and copy the results over to other shapes with the same parameters. Translation invariance ensures that such optimization is faithful.

Floating point, on the other hand, is NOT translation-invariant:

```
0.0002 - 0.0001 != (0.0002 - 1000000) - (0.0002 - 1000000) // this example in single precision
```

This causes sometimes very nasty surprises that are difficult to debug.

Comment: Integers are translation-independent, but floats are much closer than integers to being scale-independent.  Also note that even integer maths are often not nearly so translation-invariant as one might want, since language designers don't think it's important to define operators such that `(a+b) % b` is always equal `a % b`.